# How to print variable inside function?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have a function:

```
fold_wrap :: (a -> a -> a) -> (Prop -> a) -> a -> Wrapper -> a

fold_wrap v x z (Mrappe l r)   = v ( v(v x z l) v(v x z r) )
fold_wrap v x z (Wrap f)       = x f 
fold_warp v x z (Wtail )       = z
```

Where I encounter the following error:

```
mast: mast.hs:(15,1)-(16,31): Non-exhaustive patterns in function fold_mast
```

So I added

```
fold_wrap v x z _ = z
```

Which fixed the error but

Which led me to believe that some patterns were indeed left unmatched.

Now my intuition to fixing this was to print what gets passed  to the function.

So I added  this

```
fold_wrap  v x z g = print g
```

But that didnt work either since the the function has to return an `a` type and not `IO`

So my question is:

How do I print `g` and return some dummy value at the same time ?

Tips on how to fix this non exhaustive pattern matching are also appreciated.

Comment: Post the _full_ code. Enable warnings with `-Wall` so that the unmatched cases are reported at compile time. You can't print unless you return a value inside the IO monad -- read a tutorial.

Comment: thanks for the `-Wall` recommendation, I have noticed that I have copy pasted your answer from earlier without deobfusciating the names, now it works, I wish I'd think before copy pasting, cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak to your non-exhaustive pattern problem without seeing the definition of `Wrapper` that you're using. I can, however, answer the question you've asked.

Normally, in Haskell, to print a value, we need to have `IO` in our return type. This keeps the code functionality pure and gives us tons of benefits, so we should never try to break this rule in production code.

*However*, there's always that pesky little voice in your head that wants to print a value for debugging purposes only. Bear in mind, this should *never* be done in a finished product; it's only for debugging reasons. However, for this reason, Haskell provides a module `Debug.Trace` which breaks all sanity and normal functional rules to let you do this.

```
import Debug.Trace

fold_wrap v x z g = traceShow g someDummyValue
```

Now, there are a few considerations. First, `Wrapper` still has to have `Show`. There's nothing we can do about that; if Haskell doesn't know *how* to print something, then it can't print it, even for debugging. Second, Haskell is non-strict, so when you run the code, you need to make sure the `fold_wrap` call is actually evaluated. Just calling it and binding the result to a dummy variable won't do; you need to actually take that dummy value and use it in some context where it absolutely has to be evaluated, usually by printing it out in `main`.

I said this before, but I'll say it again because it's important. `Debug.Trace` is *for debugging only*. It can get addicting, especially if you're new to Haskell. But *do not* use that module in production code. It has a lot of problems, such as not guaranteeing print order, that don't matter when debugging but matter *a lot* when used in user-facing code. Not to mention the fact that it breaks every Haskell rule in the book.

Comment: am I correct to assume that `traceShow` returns the same type as `g` ?

Comment: `traceShow` returns the type of whatever the dummy value (the second argument) is. So it could be the same as `g` but doesn't necessarily have to be. You can see a full list of the different tracing functions and all their type signatures on the [Hackage page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html)

Comment: `traceShow :: Show a => a -> b -> b`. You pass it a thing to print and a value, it prints the thing and returns that value.

Comment: that answers my question more than enough, thanks everyone

Comment: An alternative for this situation might be to use `error $ print g`. When I'm debugging an unexpected pattern match, that's how I usually deal with it. Especially when the alternative is "return a dummy value".